# Why file writing permission is not set correctly in Java 7?

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-7, file-permissions

Could somebody explain me, why writing permission isn't set for others by the following code snippet on Ubuntu 13.04 and java 1.7 (OpenJDK 64bit). All other permissions are set correctly, except the writing for others, which I think is suspicious.

```
public void testCreateFileWithPermissions() throws IOException {
    Path target = Paths.get(TEST_FILE);
    cadf.createFileWithPermissions(target, "rwxrwxrwx");
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = Files.getPosixFilePermissions(target);
    for (PosixFilePermission perm : perms) {
      System.out.println(perm.toString());
    }
  }

public void createFileWithPermissions(Path target, String permissions)
      throws IOException {
    Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions
        .fromString(permissions);
    FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr = PosixFilePermissions
        .asFileAttribute(perms);
    Files.createFile(target, attr);
  }
```

I got the following output:

```
OWNER_WRITE
OTHERS_EXECUTE
GROUP_READ
OWNER_READ
GROUP_EXECUTE
GROUP_WRITE
OWNER_EXECUTE
OTHERS_READ
```

Comment: It could be the umask ?...what's umask you have in your environment.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, my umask is `0002`. I wasn't aware of `umask` and it's functionality.

Answer (score 4):

According to CPU 100 comment, I made a quick search about `umask` and it turned out I was on the default value, which is `0002`. Thus, I couldn't create any files with writting permissions for other users.
Here is a good explanation of [umask](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html).

Answer (score 2):

Since changing the umask was no option for me I use `Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Path, Set<PosixFilePermission>)` after creating the file.

Comment: It does not work even after changing umask on ubuntu